# simple WPF data binding results in StackOverFlow exception

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following XAML in my WPF project:

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindToLocalVars.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="150,94,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=value1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="150,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=value2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Label Content="Value 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.577,-0.602"/>
    <Label Content="Value1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

And the following code in my code-behind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DataBindToLocalVars
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string value1
    {
        get { return value1; }
        set
        {
            value1 = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChange("value1");
        }
    }
    public string value2 {
        get { return value2; }
        set {
        value2 = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChange("value2");
    } }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        value1 = "20";
        value2 = "40"; 
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propName)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
}
```

I am implementing the INotifyPropertyChange interface to be notified when the properties value1 and value2 change. But running this code gives me a stack overflow exception. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your cause:

```
public string value1
{
    get { return value1; }
    set
    {
        value1 = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChange("value1");
    }
}
```

Your property getters and setters are entirely recursive (they result in calls to themselves).

Idiomatic C# uses PascalCasing for property names, so how about:

```
private string value1;

public string Value1
{
    get { return value1; }
    set
    {
        value1 = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChange("Value1");
    }
}
```

Here the getter and setter uses the private `value1` field.

You also have an issue in your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.  When an event has no subscribers, then the handler will be `null`.  You need to guard against this or you'll get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I am now getting NullReferenceException in my NotifyPropertyChange() event handler.

Comment: @tutiplain you have two bugs.  I've added a fix for that one.

Comment: This solution works, but I don't understand why I must check if PropertyChanged is null.  All the event handling examples I've checked out so far do it. Why would PropertyChanged ever be null? I know I'm not explicitly assigning to it, but that by the time the event is raised its value would not be null.

Comment: When there are no subscribers to an event the delegate will be `null`.  This check should be present on raising any event, it's not specific to `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is you are setting the property with in the property
you need to set a private member with in the property then you raise property changed so Binding objects will be notified to sample it.

Firstly please use capital letters.

```
   private int _value1;
   public int Value1
   {
      get{ return _value1; }
      set
      { 
          _value1 = value;
          NotifyPropertyChange("Value1"); 
      }
   }
```

EDIT :

What .Net version are you running on .? 
I remember an issue in .net 4 where you had to do this .

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delelgate{};
```

So the event won't be null before the binding subscribes to it.

Comment: Not working, either. NotifyPropertyChange now throws a NullReferenceException.